# Spring Cannot Run on Server where is the Error?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

`enter code here`i am new in spring i typed a program but it is not running on Server i don't know where is the Problem below are the code

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>FirstSpringMVCProject</display-name>
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 </servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" >

<bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />
<bean id="/welcom.html" class="com.ismail.hellocontroller.HelloController"></bean>
<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix">
<value>/WEB-INF/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
<value>.jsp</value>
</property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

HelloController

```
package com.ismail.hellocontroller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;


public class HellloController extends AbstractController {
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    {
    ModelAndView modelandview = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
    modelandview.addObject("welcomemessage","Hi User , WelCome to The First MVC Project");
    return modelandview;
    }

}
```

when i start to run the program it show the following error 
[RuntimeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJX46.png)

[/HelloPage.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7wtK.png)

Comment: add the entire stack trace

Comment: Hope you mean this

Comment: didn't understand. Stacktrace is what you posted on the PNG screenshot but I want entire stacktrace.

Comment: may be you tried to add the stacktrace in your questions but you didn't . Only "enter code here" is displayed

Comment: type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception

Comment: I cannot help you. This is the only first three rows of the log. Please update your questions with entire error.

Comment: @JonasDavid: i think you missed to mention the spring-dispatchservlet.xml in web.xml. Replace servlet tag in web.xml with below tag     <servlet>
 <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
 servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> <init-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value>/WEB-INF/mysabisabi-servlet.xml</param-value> </init-param>    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> </servlet>  .. Also share full stack trace